# Rate of global resource consumption

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok sorry of this is a dumb question but really appreciate your help.

The US constitutes $5\%$ of the world's population and consumes $20\%$ of its resources. In order for everyone on the planet to consume resources at that rate (based on current resources) how many times larger would the planet's current resources have to be to sustain $100\%$ of the world's population consuming at the same rate as the US.

Answer (score 1):

Although the tag says abstract algebra, the following is an algebra-free calculation (not that I have anything against ex). Choose our resources unit so that current world consumption is $100$.  So the US consumes $20$.

Think of the US population as having $5$ population units. (That makes a population unit about $60$ million people, but we don't need to know that.)

Each population unit in the US consumes $4$ units of resources. So $100$ population units (the whole world) would consume $400$ resource units.